# How can I split and trim a string into parts all on one line?

Tags: c#, .net, split, trim

I want to split this line:

```
string line = "First Name ; string ; firstName";
```

into an array of their trimmed versions:

```
"First Name"
"string"
"firstName"
```

**How can I do this all on one line?** The following gives me an error "cannot convert type void":

```
List<string> parts = line.Split(';').ToList().ForEach(p => p.Trim());
```

Comment: The error is returned because `ForEach` works on current instance of `IEnumerable` and returns `void`.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Try

```
List<string> parts = line.Split(';').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
```

FYI, the Foreach method takes an Action (takes T and returns void) for parameter, and your lambda return a string as string.Trim return a string

Foreach extension method is meant to modify the state of objects within the collection. As string are immutable, this would have no effect

Comment: Note: `ForEach` is not an extension method.

Comment: Best solution in Linq!

Comment: What if there are no values does it return null?

Comment: if line is null then you get an exception. if line does not contain ';' you'll have a list with one string corresponding to the trimmid line

Answer (score 27):

The `ForEach` method doesn't return anything, so you can't assign that to a variable.

Use the `Select` extension method instead:

```
List<string> parts = line.Split(';').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 21):

After .net 5, the solution is as simple as:

```cs
string[] parts = line.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
```

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Finally!!!!!   (cue CeCe Peniston: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xk8mm1Qmt-Y )

Comment: Needs a `.ToList()` at the end.

Answer (score 6):

Because p.Trim() returns a new string.

You need to use:

```
List<string> parts = line.Split(';').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an extension method...

```
    public static string[] SplitAndTrim(this string text, char separator)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return text.Split(separator).Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively try this:

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, "\\s*;\\s*");
```

Comment: This is a great idea, however, I believe that misses any trailing blanks at the end of the string, correct?

Answer (score 2):

try using Regex :

```
List<string> parts = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(line, @"\s*;\s*").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Split returns string[] type.  Write an extension method:

```
public static string[] SplitTrim(this string data, char arg)
{
    string[] ar = data.Split(arg);
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
    {
        ar[i] = ar[i].Trim();
    }
    return ar;
}
```

I liked your solution so I decided to add to it and make it more usable.

```
public static string[] SplitAndTrim(this string data, char[] arg)
{
    return SplitAndTrim(data, arg, StringSplitOptions.None);
}

public static string[] SplitAndTrim(this string data, char[] arg, 
StringSplitOptions sso)
{
    string[] ar = data.Split(arg, sso);
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
        ar[i] = ar[i].Trim();
    return ar;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Regex

```js
string a="bob, jon,man; francis;luke; lee bob";
   String pattern = @"[,;\s]";
            String[] elements = Regex.Split(a, pattern).Where(item=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item)).Select(item=>item.Trim()).ToArray();;   
            foreach (string item in elements){
                Console.WriteLine(item.Trim());
```

Result:

bob

jon

man

francis

luke

lee

bob

Explain pattern [,;\s]: Match one occurrence of either the , ; or space character