# Perform Trim() while using Split()

Tags: c#, string, trim

today I was wondering if there is a better solution perform the following code sample.

```
string keyword = " abc, foo  ,     bar";
string match = "foo";
string[] split= keyword.Split(new char[] { ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string s in split)
{
  if(s.Trim() == match){// asjdklasd; break;}
}
```

Is there a way to perform trim() without manually iterating through each item? I'm looking for something like 'split by the following chars and automatically trim each result'.

Ah, immediatly before posting I found

```
List<string> parts = line.Split(';').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
```

in [How can I split and trim a string into parts all on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728303/how-can-i-split-and-trim-a-string-into-parts-all-on-one-line)

Still I'm curious: Might there be a better solution to this? (Or would the compiler probably convert them to the same code output as the Linq-Operation?)

Comment: define "better"... you mean more readable? faster?

Comment: Faster/more performant while not loosing the readability. Like Marc Gravell's anwser.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Another possible option (that avoids LINQ, for better or worse):

```
string line = " abc, foo  ,     bar";
string[] parts= Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(','), p => p.Trim());
```

However, if you just need to know if it is there - perhaps short-circuit?

```
bool contains = line.Split(',').Any(p => p.Trim() == match);
```

Comment: Oh, yeah you are absolutly right. Seems that I have to get used to the Any() Method ;)

thanks

Comment: The answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728303/how-can-i-split-and-trim-a-string-into-parts-all-on-one-line is more elegant maybe?

Comment: @Morty Yeah, maybe. But you'll find that business rules are far more important than implementation details. Besides, both solutions work, so it's just good we have options.

Comment: The Array.ConvertAll() is not available in .NET Compact Framework.

Answer (score 17):

```
var parts = line
    .Split(';')
    .Select(p => p.Trim())
    .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This also removes blank (IsNullOrWhiteSpace) entries, so that " abc, foo  ,  ,   bar"  (extra comma) gives 3 trimmed results rather than 4. This is what I needed, but didn't see this until I'd rolled my own :)

Answer (score 8):

I know this is 10 years too late but you could have just split by ' ' as well:

```
string[] split= keyword.Split(new char[] { ',', ';', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Because you're also splitting by the space char AND instructing the split to remove the empty entries, you'll have what you need.

Comment: You might've been 10 years too late for the OP, but this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: This assumes there are no spaces in the individual entries though, otherwise those will be split up into separate words.

Answer (score 6):

If spaces just surrounds the words in the comma separated string this will work:

```
var keyword = " abc, foo  ,     bar";
var array = keyword.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
if (array.Contains("foo"))
{
    Debug.Print("Match");
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work if a single value contain 1 or more spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using regular expressions on the original string, looking for the pattern "any number of spaces followed by one of your delimiters followed by one or more spaces" and remove those spaces.  Then split.

Comment: Regex, haven't thought of that either, but you are right, would be a another possible solution. thanks

Comment: I would be very much against using regular expressions for such a trivial problem. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html regarding "now you have two problems."

Comment: Well I'm hopeless at writing regular expressions, and would screw it up, so I wouldn't use it either TBH, but this seems a fairly simply pattern to search and replace and I would have thought would be faster than any method that does a .Trim() on each element after splitting.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string keyword = " abc, foo  ,     bar";
string match = "foo";
string[] split = Regex.Split(keyword.Trim(), @"\s*[,;]\s*");
if (split.Contains(match))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with .Net 5, there is an easier option:

```
string[] split= keyword.Split(new char[] { ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
```

You can combine it with the option to remove empty entries:

```
string[] split= keyword.Split(new char[] { ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to find a lot of different methods of doing this and the performance change and accuracy isn't going to be readily apparent.  I'd recommend plugging them all into a testing suite like NUnit in order both to find which one comes out on top AND which ones are accurate.

Use small, medium, and large amounts of text in loops to examine the various situations.