# .Contains() is checking only first element of string[] .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, split

I'm trying to check does the values of (string[]) contains in string. When I run the code only first value of string separated with comma is check. I want to check all values of string.

```
 // Model property (User)
 // Example 1002, 5000, 3300 (Skills ids)
 public string userSkillsId { get; set; }

 // Index filtering with multiple values(select2)
 // Example 1002, 5000 (Skills ids to check if contains in userSkillsId)
 public string SkillsId { get; set; } 

 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ContestantViewModel viewModel, int currentPage)
 {
     string[] skills = viewModel.SkillsId?.Split(",");

     if (!(viewModel.SkillsId is null))
        entity = entity.Where(x => ((IList)skills).Contains(x.userSkillsId));

     viewModel.Result = result;
  }
```

Comment: maybe spaces are the issue, try
Split(",").Select(p => p.Trim();

Comment: "first value of string separated with comma is check. " - how do you see this happens? You mean if you need to check if `"abc"` is in array, then `Contains` returns `true` if `"abc"` is the first element of the array, and `false` if it's the second, third and so on ?

Comment: `((IList)skills)` Why are you doing that cast?

Comment: Can you talk us through why `userSkillsId` is modelled as a string rather than an array / list? `Trim` will fix your immediate issue, but my greater concern is your modelling is wrong.

Comment: I'am here:

            List<string> parts = viewModel.SkillsId?.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();

            if (!(parts is null))
                entity = entity.Where(x => parts.Contains(x.userSkillsId));

when property  string x.userSkillsId  == 1992,1003,5555 .Contains get only 1992. I want to check others too.  If i convert string x.userSkillsId to ArrayList framework will create another table for that property, I do not want it.

Answer (score 0):

use separator as char

string[] skills = viewModel.SkillsId?.Split(',');

Comment: No effect, thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: what the object is entity?

Comment: var entity = _contestantsService.GetAllAsNoTrackingMapped();

Comment: public IQueryable<ContestantViewModel> GetAllAsNoTrackingMapped()
        {
            return contestantRepository.Set().AsNoTracking().To<ContestantViewModel>();
        }

Comment: @Beso You will need to trim using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977340/perform-trim-while-using-split/63521558#63521558 (since the SkillsId has whitespace in it). That is the issue.