# Add a single string that contains multiple list items?

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a string that contains multiple values:

```
private string serverList = "Server 1, Server 2, Server 3";
```

Is it possible to add these values into a list? 
Clearly if I just use List.Add(serverList); I will get all 3 as a single element. What I need is 3 separate elements for serverList.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728303/how-can-i-split-and-trim-a-string-into-parts-all-on-one-line

Comment: Please remove the tag 'unity' as it is not related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Split` method to break your string up into an array

```
string[] servers = serverList.Split(',');
```

Comment: Note that using the single-character `(',')` will return all of the strings with the prepended space - it might be more useful to use `(", ")`

Comment: True, or just trim out whitespace when adding them to the list

Answer (score 3):

```
serverList.Split(',').Select(server => server.Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that since `Split` is defined with `params` it's completely unnecessary to specify a `new string[]`. Also, this code won't compile - `','` is a `char` and not a `string` because you used single quotes

Comment: @Aravol you are right.. I goofed up while making edits. I have corrected it now.. Thanks.. May I suggest that feel free to edit posts, when you see such obvious errors (notepad complied as they call it).. I am sure original author will appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string serverList = "Server 1,Server 2,Server 3";

List<string> listServers = new List<string>{};

listServers.AddRange(serverList.Split(',')); //  utilize AddRange instead of Add
```

[List.AddRange Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)